# What prevent users from messing with database data?

Tags: database

I am developing a database application using c# and MySQL , the application is about tracking employee training courses. After reading several topics in Stack Overflow I came to the conclusion that I should make one database user for each application role. I have 2 types of users in that system: admin and regular users. So U should make 2 users in MySQL, one admin with full access to the database and another regular user with some limits. And there should be a users's table with user names, salt and password hashes.

During the operation of the application my (c#) application is checking for certain stuff before doing some operations, for example my application should check to see if the employee have taken course A before allowing him to take course B.
Now what prevent a user from reverse engineering my C# application getting the database user name and password, connecting to the database using MySQL Workbench and messing with the data by for example entering course B without having course A first?

I was thinking about using stored procedure but if all or most processing goes into stored procedures that would but huge load on the database server, no ?

Answer (score 1):

The most secure way of controlling database access is to use the logon id of the current user. That way there is no possibility of anyone reverse engineering the username and password. You do this by putting `IntegratedSecurity=yes` in the connection string.

Ideally, you would create two roles - admin and normal - and give each role the privileges it needs, and then assign each user to a role. However, it appears that MySQL doesn't support roles out of the box (but it seems that Google may have an extension which does something similar). If roles aren't available, then you just have to assign privileges for each user appropriately.

Stored Procedures should not contain too much 'business' logic, but only 'data' logic such as ensuring data is valid, audited (if required), and so on. My opinion is also that SP's should only do set operations and never use a cursor; not everybody agrees with me, though.